# Setting single models in django

Tags: django, model-view-controller, model

I want to store some single data of my web-site. Actually, I want to set articles that I want to display at the start page, popular tags and another stuff.

Django offers me to make a model, so it is supposed that there are lots of such data.

How to realize this task in the right way? May be my approach is completely wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that you have data that you need to display on every page?

Comment: Well you could simply use to some DS like tuples to store and display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider looking at a CMS, Django-CMS is getting quite mature.

Aside from that, it sounds like you need to store some one-off or singleton objects.  You can most certainly use models for this as it will not only help you think properly about your data structures and learn about this powerful Django DB abstraction, but I suspect that you'll find rather quickly that you may indeed want to create multiple objects over time (its is often rare that you don't).

If you have something that really is and always should be a singleton, consider placing it in your settings.py file instead.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want using CMS for now. So I should still use models.